# Exclude route from express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, middleware

I have a node app sitting like a firewall/dispatcher in front of other micro services and it uses a middleware chain like below:

```
...
app.use app_lookup
app.use timestamp_validator
app.use request_body
app.use checksum_validator
app.use rateLimiter
app.use whitelist
app.use proxy
...
```

However for a particular GET route I want to skip all of them except rateLimiter and proxy. Is their a way to set a filter like a Rails before_filter using :except/:only?

Comment: You can user 'express-unless' npm for this purpose.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Even though there is no build-in middleware filter system in expressjs, you can achieve this in at least two ways.

First method is to mount all middlewares that you want to skip to a regular expression path than includes a negative lookup:

```
// Skip all middleware except rateLimiter and proxy when route is /example_route
app.use(/\/((?!example_route).)*/, app_lookup);
app.use(/\/((?!example_route).)*/, timestamp_validator);
app.use(/\/((?!example_route).)*/, request_body);
app.use(/\/((?!example_route).)*/, checksum_validator);
app.use(rateLimiter);
app.use(/\/((?!example_route).)*/, whitelist);
app.use(proxy);
```

Second method, probably more readable and cleaner one, is to wrap your middleware with a small helper function:

```
var unless = function(path, middleware) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (path === req.path) {
            return next();
        } else {
            return middleware(req, res, next);
        }
    };
};

app.use(unless('/example_route', app_lookup));
app.use(unless('/example_route', timestamp_validator));
app.use(unless('/example_route', request_body));
app.use(unless('/example_route', checksum_validator));
app.use(rateLimiter);
app.use(unless('/example_route', whitelist));
app.use(proxy);
```

If you need more powerfull route matching than simple `path === req.path` you can use [path-to-regexp module](https://github.com/component/path-to-regexp) that is used internally by Express.

UPDATE :- In `express 4.17` `req.path` returns only '/', so use `req.baseUrl` :

```
var unless = function(path, middleware) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (path === req.baseUrl) {
            return next();
        } else {
            return middleware(req, res, next);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: The path-to-regexp module linked here is deprecated. Here's the correct one: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm wondering why anyone pointed that regular expressions are broken. When route is `/example_route`, your regex still matches `/` so route is not skipped. @guillaume gave correct one few answers below: `/^\/(?!path1|pathn).*$/`

Comment: What if I have an auth middleware and then a validate middleware and then my controller. If auth fails I want to skip over validate and let my controller do the logging and then send the response… is this bad practise? Can I just add a flag to the req in the auth middleware and then eval the flag in validate to skip validate and then eval again in my controller? Or can I skip straight to controller somehow? … next(‘controller’) maybe?

Answer (score 56):

Built upon the answer from @lukaszfiszer as I wanted more than one route excluded.
You can add as many as you want here.

```
var unless = function(middleware, ...paths) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    const pathCheck = paths.some(path => path === req.path);
    pathCheck ? next() : middleware(req, res, next);
  };
};

app.use(unless(redirectPage, "/user/login", "/user/register"));
```

Can't add as comment sorry.

Comment: Great answer. Should be the solution.

Comment: I agree this deserves more upvotes. Simple and concise.

Comment: Just to convert it all to ES6 and a one-liner: 

`const unless = (middleware, ...paths) => (req, res, next) => paths.some(path => path === req.path) ? next() : middleware(req, res, next);`

Comment: Beautiful solution. Would be nice if it accepted `/users/:id/login`

Comment: @EricGuan You could achieve that with a little tweak to the path check. instead of `path === req.path`  you could use some logic to check for the section of the path which is dynamic and stripping it out or ignoring it. perhaps a regex would do it best

Comment: passing `paths` as an array and defining them as constant elsewhere as `ECLUDED_APIS: ['api/v1/auth/login', ...]` is awesome, using it this way.

Answer (score 23):

You can also skip route like this by putting a condition on req.originalUrl:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.originalUrl === '/api/login') {
    return next();
    } else {
         //DO SOMETHING
    }
```

Comment: Not technically wrong, but doesn't really cover dynamic paths such as `/:user/stuff`

Answer (score 4):

I use this regular expression with success : `/^\/(?!path1|pathn).*$/`.

Comment: I like this one! But I would try not to use it for servers which are under heavy load. I would try to omit RegExps on Routes. RegExp matching is indeed fast, but string comparison is a lot faster.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of good answers here. I needed a slightly different answer though.

I wanted to be able to exclude middleware from all HTTP PUT requests. So I created a more general version of the `unless` function that allows a predicate to be passed in:

```js
function unless(pred, middleware) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (pred(req)) {
            next(); // Skip this middleware.
        }
        else {
            middleware(req, res, next); // Allow this middleware.
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```js
app.use(unless(req => req.method === "PUT", bodyParser.json()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define some routes like below.

```
 app.use(/\/((?!route1|route2).)*/, (req, res, next) => {

    //A personal middleware
    //code

    next();//Will call the app.get(), app.post() or other
 });
```

Comment: Hello, please add some explanation to your answer and also formatting to your code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used part of answers posted yet to override original `app.use`

```js
const unless = ( route, middleware ) => {
    return ( req, res, next ) => {
        if ( req.originalUrl.startsWith( route + '/' ) ) {
            return next();
        } else {
            return middleware( req, res, next );
        }
    };
};

const filteredRoute = '/myapi';  // Route to filter and subroute

const origUse = app.use;
app.use = function ( ...callbacks ) {
    if ( !callbacks.length ) throw new Error( '.use() method requires at least one function' );
    if ( typeof callbacks[0] ==='string' ) {
        if ( !( callbacks.length -1 ) ) throw new Error( '.use() method requires at least one function' );
        const route = callbacks.shift();
        for ( let i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++ ) {
            origUse.call( this, route, unless( filteredRoute, callbacks[i] ) );
        }
    } else {
        for ( let i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++ ) {
            origUse.call( this, unless( filteredRoute, callbacks[i] ) );
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using `path-to-regexp` as @lukaszfiszer's answer suggests:

```js
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';

const unless = (
  paths: pathToRegexp.Path,
  middleware: RequestHandler
): RequestHandler => {
  const regex = pathToRegexp(paths);
  return (req, res, next) =>
    regex.exec(req.url) ? next() : middleware(req, res, next);
};

export default unless;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved this is by setting up a middleware for a specific path like so

```
app.use("/routeNeedingAllMiddleware", middleware1);
app.use("/routeNeedingAllMiddleware", middleware2);
app.use("/routeNeedingAllMiddleware", middleware3);
app.use("/routeNeedingAllMiddleware", middleware4);
```

and then setting up my routes like so

```
app.post("/routeNeedingAllMiddleware/route1", route1Handler);
app.post("/routeNeedingAllMiddleware/route2", route2Handler);
```

For the other special route that doesn't need all the middleware, we setup another route like so

```js
app.use("/routeNeedingSomeMiddleware", middleware2);
app.use("/routeNeedingSomeMiddleware", middleware4);
```

and then setting up the corresponding route like so

```
app.post("/routeNeedingSomeMiddleware/specialRoute", specialRouteHandler);
```

The Express documentation for this is available [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Answer (score 0):

Improved upon @Geelie's answer with added types:

```
import {Request, Response, NextFunction, Handler} from "express";

const unless = (middleware: Handler, ...paths: RegExp[]): Handler => {
  return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const pathCheck = paths.some(path => path.test(req.path));
    pathCheck ? next() : middleware(req, res, next);
  };
};

app.use(unless(redirectPage, new RegExp("/user/login"), new RegExp("/user/register")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make sure that if I hit all other methods except **POST /user/login**, then I should get 404 - Not Found
And same for **POST /user/signup**

```
router.post("/signup", userSignup).all("*", (req, res) => res.sendStatus(404));
router.post("/login", userLogin).all("*", (req, res) => res.sendStatus(404));
router.get("/:id", getParticularUser);
router.patch("/:id", editUserDetails);
```

Above solved my problem, just posting if this is regarding what I wanted to know.