# How to use a route specific middleware of express in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to use this library ([keycloak-connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect)) for authentication and authorization. It has a global middleware that can be directly used by `app.use()` method or by wrapping a nestjs middlewareclass around it. But how to use the route specific express middleware which is used to protect individual routes?.

Example usage in plain express app

```
app.get( '/protected', keycloak.protect('adminRole'), handler );
```

The protect method returns a plain express middleware with signature `function(req, res, next)`

Comment: If you want keycloack for auth, maybe consider using Guards instead. You can easily attach guard to method, controller or globally.

Comment: But how can I use that express middleware in guard?

Comment: Check accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117337/exclude-route-from-express-middleware

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your "handler" is a method (decorated with either `GET`, or `POST`, etc) in a class decorated with `@Controller`.
The module importing this **controller** is supposed to declare the middleware.

Example:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [YourController],
})
export class YourModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(keyCloack.protect('adminRole'))
      .forRoutes('/protected');
  }
}
```

Where `YourController` contains the handler for the route '/protected'.

Implementing `NestModule` is the key. Then you're obliged to declare `configure` and can use the `consumer`.

Comment: Where do you get the keyCloack instance from? Shoudn't it be possible to integrate it into an @AuthGuard? A link to an example keycaloak + naestjs setup would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know this library, sorry, I reused `keyCloack` because it was provided "as is" in the OP's code.   
However,  I assume that you can create a custom provider for it, and register/export it in a custom/dedicated `@Module`. See "Dependency Injection" in the NestJS documentation.
Modules and Guards can inject providers too. Thus, the example of `YourModule` I gave could have a constructor like `constructor(@Inject(KEYCLOACK) private keyCloack: SomeType) {}` and use `this.keyCloack` in its method. The same is true for a Guard.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want your middleware to be applied on the routes in a controller, you may -

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
 configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
 consumer
  .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
  .forRoutes(CatsController);
 }
}
```

Comment: This saved my day, for some reason path was not getting applied by controller directly it started working