# Express JS - Regular expression - Everything except

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I'm using ExpressJS 4.x to develop a REST web server.
What I'm trying to do is to write a middleware that catches all the incoming requests, except the ones that begin with "/api/..."

Which regular expression can I use?

```
//This middleware catches everything except the requests addressed to "/api/..."
app.use('<regular_expression>',express.static('public'));

//Not intercepted by the middleware
app.get("/api/foo1",function(req,res)=>{
    ......
})

//Not intercepted by the middleware
app.get("/api/foo2/bar",function(req,res)=>{
    ......
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117337/exclude-route-from-express-middleware), you can use [negative look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (they are available in [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)):

```
app.use(/\/((?!api).)*/, app_lookup);
```

As you can see, the regular expression is not surrounded by quotes.

Comment: This is the exact regular expression I'm using in production.  So I can confirm this works too.