# Can I set multiple rate limits for the same routes with express-rate-limit?

Tags: node.js, express, express-rate-limit

Can I set a global `rateLimit` for my express server and also set a more restrictive `rateLimit` for some routes?

For example:

```
const globalLimit = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,        // 1 HOUR
  max: 500                         // MAX 500 REQUESTS
});

const apiLimit = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,        // 1 HOUR
  max: 100                         // MAX 100 REQUESTS
});

const someRouteLimit = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,        // 1 HOUR
  max: 10                          // MAX 10 REQUESTS
});


app.use("/", globalLimit);         // ALL ROUTES WILL BE LIMITED BY THE globalLimit
app.use("/api", apiLimit);         // API ROUTES WILL BE LIMITED BY THE apiLimit

app.get("/some-route", someRouteLimit, routeHandler);  // THIS ROUTE WILL BE LIMITED BY THE someRouteLimit
```

Will it work the way I intend? Is this normal use of the `express-rate-limit` package or is this an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`express-rate-limit` is quite a popular package. So I don't think it is an anti-pattern.

Middleware can be chained.

For example, you want to impose both `someRouteLimit` and `apiLimit` on `/some-route`

```js
app.get("/some-route",apiLimit,someRouteLimit,routeHandler)
```

The middleware is executed in order so you want to put the more restrictive one after the laxer one.

Express middleware hierarchy:

1. Application-level middleware
2. Router-level middleware

`app.use("/", globalLimit)` is an application-level middleware so it will be executed first before all other middleware but before/after other application-level middleware depending on the order of which they are called.

You can also group routes using routers and apply the rate limit middleware on specific routers.

In your `app.js` or `index.js`:

```js
// Depedencies
const express = require('express')
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')

// Initialize the app
const app = express()

const globalLimit = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,        // 1 HOUR
  max: 500                         // MAX 500 REQUESTS
});

const apiLimit = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,        // 1 HOUR
  max: 100                         // MAX 100 REQUESTS
});


// Load Routes
const routeOne = require('./routes/routeOne');
const routeTwo = require('./routes/routeTwo');

// Use routes
app.use('/', routeOne,apiLimit); // Impose apiLimit on this router
app.use('/', routeTwo);          // No router-level middleware is applied

app.listen(portNumber)
```

In the routeOne: (restricted by both `globalLimit` and `apiLimit`)

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')

const someRouteLimit = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,        // 1 HOUR
  max: 10                          // MAX 10 REQUESTS
});


// Some Route (further restricted by someRouteLimit)
router.post('/some-route',someRouteLimit, routeHandler);

module.exports = router;
```

In RouteTwo: (Restricted by `globalLimit` but not `apiLimit`)

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')

const someRouteLimit2 = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,        // 1 HOUR
  max: 10                          // MAX 10 REQUESTS
});


// Some Route (further restricted by someRouteLimit2)
router.post('/some-route2',someRouteLimit, routeHandler);

module.exports = router;
```

If you want to implement your middleware in a more customized manner, there are some more creative methods using regex and custom helper function in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117337/exclude-route-from-express-middleware).